# Why isn't python optimising the function declaration out of the loop?

Tags: python, function, optimization

Consider:

`Code A`

```
def foo(): 
    pass

for i in range(1000000):
    foo()
```

`Code B`

```
for i in range(1000000):
    def foo():
        pass
    foo()
```

The only difference between the two code snippets are that `foo` is constantly redefined inside the loop at each iteration.

Running some benchmark tests:

`Code A`

```
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop
```

`Code B`

```
10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop
```

So, constant redefinition of the function is an unwanted overhead.

Here's what the byte code of `Code B` looks like:

```
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              39 (to 42)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                25 (to 41)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  2          19 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object foo at 0x103113390, file "<dis>", line 2>)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
             25 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             28 STORE_NAME               2 (foo)

  4          31 LOAD_NAME                2 (foo)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             37 POP_TOP
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   41 POP_BLOCK
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the function definition has not been optimised out of the loop (see line `25 MAKE_FUNCTION`).

This would seem simple enough, to move the function creation out of the loop, since its declaration obviously is not conditional to loop execution.

Is there any glaring obstacle that prevents this from being done?

Comment: Python does very little optimization, in general.

Comment: (You could just as easily ask why it doesn't optimize out the entire loop.)

Comment: Did you try [Pypy](https://pypy.org/), a just in time compiler?

Comment: If you can prove the codeblock generated is *never* going to differ and will *never* have a dependency on `i` being in scope then I imagine you could move it out... However, at that point you can prove its never changed, you've already had to do that by going through the entire loop... That may just have been consistent for this run based on inputs that might not hold true next run.

Comment: Because in the interpreter, as opposed to compiled code, it is too late. You have already entered the loop. Due to the dynamic object (type!) creation,  python can not generally afford to look ahead across the scope boundaries before the code actually runs.

Comment: This is a legitimate question (imo). All I wanted to know was why it could not be done. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows a lot of things to be reassigned or modified at runtime. For example, when compiling this code, Python can't determine whether some part of your program might do something like

```
import builtins

builtins.range = lambda *args: []
```

in which case moving the `foo` definition out of the loop would be wrong, because the `foo` definition should never execute.

There are lots and lots of crazy things you can do in Python that can change the meaning of code in unexpected ways. To optimize in spite of such possibilities really requires a JIT compiler, but the standard implementation of Python doesn't have one of those.

Comment: Thanks. This made sense. In answering the question "why it isn't done", it makes sense to talk about "why it shouldn't be done" in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where the optimization you suggest wouldn't work

```
foo = None

def range(n):
    global foo
    def foo():
        print('hi')
    for i in (1,2,3):
        yield i

def foo():
    pass

for i in range(1000000):
    foo()
```

My output:

```
hi
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you want to change the function definition at runtime?

```
for i in range(1000000):
    if(True):
        def foo():
            pass
    if("some bits decide to flip"=="some bits decide to flip"):
        def foo():
            i=i+1
            pass
    foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since python doesn't know if you are capturing something within the scope he can not optimize that. If you are declaring the function inside the loop it's up to you wheter you need it to be redifined or not.
By the time python arrives to the loop the interpreter can not go out of the loop scope.